# Unable to Parse a JSON File

Tags: json, swift

This is the first time I am working with JSON. I have a JSON file to associate cities and countries with timezones. Here is a sample of the contents.

```
 [
 {
 "name": "Abidjan",
 "country": "Ivory Coast",
 "timeZoneName": "Africa/Bamako"
 },
 {
 "name": "Abu Dhabi",
 "country": "U.A.E.",
 "timeZoneName": "Asia/Dubai"
 }
]
```

I’m trying to use codable to parse the file, but a function I use to parse the file won’t work.
I have a struct for each instance in the file.

```
struct LoadedTimeZone: Codable {
    var name: String
    var country: String
    var timeZoneName: String
}
```

and I have a struct for the decoded contents to load directly into

```
struct LoadedTimeZones: Codable {
    var results: [LoadedTimeZone]
}
```

In the viewDidLoad of my UITableViewController, I added this code:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "CitiesAndTimeZones", withExtension: "json") {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                parse(json: data)
            }
        }
```

and here is the function for parse(json: Data)

```
 func parse(json: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    if let jsonTimeZones = try? decoder.decode(LoadedTimeZones.self, from: json) {
        timeZones = jsonTimeZones.results
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

timeZones is declared as `var timeZones = [LoadedTimeZone]()` right above viewDidLoad.

From some debugging I have done, it seems that jsonTimeZones returns nil.
I have looked at multiple cases on stackoverflow and over the internet, and what I have done does not seem that much different.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: "try?": That means: Hey, if it fails, I'm not interested in knowing why. It's bad habit. Use do/catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
if let jsonTimeZones = try? decoder.decode(LoadedTimeZones.self, from: json) {
```

With

```
if let jsonTimeZones = try? decoder.decode([LoadedTimeZone].self, from: json) {
```

Your root is an array and there is no key named `results` in your json

```
struct LoadedTimeZone: Codable {
    let name,country,timeZoneName: String 
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but on the next line: `timeZones = jsonTimeZones.results`, I get the error Value of type '[LoadedTimeZones]' has no member 'results'.

Comment: make it `timeZones = jsonTimeZones`